# I want to groupby id and count the unique grade and return max

Tags: python, pyspark

I have this data and try to solve the following question.

DataFrame_from_Scratch = spark.createDataFrame(values, columns)
DataFrame_from_Scratch.show()

```
columns = ['id', 'grade', 'date']
values = [('101','good','2022/06/01'), 
 ('102','good','2022/06/01'), ('103','fail','2022/06/02'), 
 ('104','poor','2022/06/02'),('101','good','2022/06/08'), 
 ('101','excellent','2022/06/14'),('102','poor','2022/06/10'), 
 ('104','good','2022/06/09'),('102','poor','2022/06/13'), 
 ('103','fail','2022/06/14')]

df.groupby(F.col('id')).agg(F.countDistinct(F.col('grade'))).show()
```

1. groupby id and count unique grade
2. what is the maximum
3. groupby id and date and how many unique date is there

Comment: Please post your data as text, not as an image. It's rather difficult to copy/paste an image for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation for the 1st question is correct. Not sure what exactly your question is seeking as an answer

But nevertheless, below are the answer for other sub-parts -

#### Data Preparation

```
columns = ['id', 'grade', 'date']
values = [('101','good','2022/06/01'), 
 ('102','good','2022/06/01'), ('103','fail','2022/06/02'), 
 ('104','poor','2022/06/02'),('101','good','2022/06/08'), 
 ('101','excellent','2022/06/14'),('102','poor','2022/06/10'), 
 ('104','good','2022/06/09'),('102','poor','2022/06/13'), 
 ('103','fail','2022/06/14')]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(values,columns)

sparkDF.show()

+---+---------+----------+
| id|    grade|      date|
+---+---------+----------+
|101|     good|2022/06/01|
|102|     good|2022/06/01|
|103|     fail|2022/06/02|
|104|     poor|2022/06/02|
|101|     good|2022/06/08|
|101|excellent|2022/06/14|
|102|     poor|2022/06/10|
|104|     good|2022/06/09|
|102|     poor|2022/06/13|
|103|     fail|2022/06/14|
+---+---------+----------+
```

#### Unique Grade Counts

```
sparkDF.groupBy(F.col('id')).agg(F.countDistinct(F.col('grade')).alias('Distinct Grade Count')).show()

+---+--------------------+
| id|Distinct Grade Count|
+---+--------------------+
|101|                   2|
|104|                   2|
|102|                   2|
|103|                   1|
+---+--------------------+
```

#### Maximum - Assuming Max Date

```
sparkDF.groupBy(F.col('id')).agg(F.max(F.col('Date')).alias('Max Date')).show()

+---+----------+
| id|  Max Date|
+---+----------+
|101|2022/06/14|
|102|2022/06/13|
|103|2022/06/14|
|104|2022/06/09|
+---+----------+
```

#### Unique Dates

Not sure about the intention behind this , as this does not makes sense based on your dataset as your granularity level is - `id` & `Date`

```
sparkDF.groupBy(['id','Date']).agg(F.countDistinct(F.col('grade')).alias('Distinct Grade Count')).orderBy('id').show()

+---+----------+--------------------+
| id|      Date|Distinct Grade Count|
+---+----------+--------------------+
|101|2022/06/14|                   1|
|101|2022/06/01|                   1|
|101|2022/06/08|                   1|
|102|2022/06/13|                   1|
|102|2022/06/01|                   1|
|102|2022/06/10|                   1|
|103|2022/06/14|                   1|
|103|2022/06/02|                   1|
|104|2022/06/09|                   1|
|104|2022/06/02|                   1|
+---+----------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am just getting started with this skill. In the first question, I want to return the id with the maximum grade, and also for unique dates I want to return the sum of all the unique date